# Calculate time of execution of junit test in jmeter without setUp and tearDown methods?

Tags: jdbc, time, junit, jmeter, load

When executing JUnit method in JMeter, there is time specified in the listeners. Does this time include the calling of the setUp and tearDown methods of the TestCase, or just the method execution? And if the time of setUp and tearDown methods executions is included, is there an option to calculate the time of execution of the test method without them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timing only include execution of method, not setup/teardown calls.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request

> Note that JMeter currently runs the test methods directly, rather than leaving it to JUnit. This is to allow the setUp/tearDown methods to be excluded from the sample time.

And see code:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/f2e65bc2f264d4bd7da83279dbdcf236da6edfe3/src/junit/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JUnitSampler.java#L389

Notice sampleStart which takes start time is called after setup